How to force specified alias case when using object syntax in .select
I am using knex.js with OracleDB, attempting to use the object syntax in a select with query builder, like below.
knex.select({ currentDate: "SYSDATE"}).from("dual")
While this works, I need the knex.js query result to return column names in camelCase, like specified in the above syntax, however, OracleDB automatically returns the column names as uppercase, regardless of the input, unless it is wrapped in double quotes, like below.
knex.select({ '"currentDate'": "SYSDATE"}).from("dual")
This will indeed return "currentDate" instead of "CURRENTDATE", but makes for much less readable syntax, especially when I am selecting from many columns and need to repeat this formatting for each individual column alias.
Is there a way in knex.js to globally override this behavior and require that knex.js automatically wrap these alias values in double quotes, so as to avoid having to do this manually?

It'd seem that the postProcessRespose option should work for your purposes:
Simplifying the example in the docs as a starting point:
function convertToCamel(result) {/* insert logic/make call to helper library/etc. here */}

const knex = require('knex')({
    // existing config 
    postProcessResponse: (result, queryContext) => {
      return convertToCamel(result);
    },
});



This looks to be a step in the right direction, but the result variable contains the results object with the column name still in uppercase, since the DB is returning it that way. I think what I need is to intercept the query before it makes its way to the DB, but there is no clear documentation on how to do that from what I've seen.

@Austin Its use case is less clear to me based on the docs but there's also the wrapIdentifier config option which mentions case conversion. If I had a working example in front of me, I'd give it a try but I don't.

I have been using wrapIdentifier already to remove the double quotes that are added to table and column names, in order to allow for case-insensitivity in those areas, but the trade-off has been losing the double quotes on aliases and it doesn't look like wrapIdentifier is able to provide the type of value passed in, in order to modify everything except alias values.
This is likely an advanced, undocumented use-case and until a full solution is found or knex.js adds additional functionality, I will go for wrapping my .select() objects in a custom function that does the transformation.
